# Mac terminal/bash open only one instance of application

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I setup some bash functions that will open applications. The code runs `subl .` to open the current directory in Sublime Text editor. If Sublime is already open it will open another instance of the application. Is it possible to open only that instance of the application, and close all the others? That way there are not multiple instances to juggle between.

Comment: Use the `open` command to emulate how `Finder` works when you click on an application.

Comment: Generally speaking, an answer to this question will be application-specific, rather than completely generic (for instance, for Emacs one would use `emacsclient` to connect to an existing instance), making it a little too broad; there's nothing built into bash (though, as Barmar has noted, there *is* tooling built into OS X) for the purpose. Asking how to do that just for Sublime would be more amenable to a testably correct, comprehensive answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just did `open -a Emacs filename` and it opened the file in my existing Emacs window. It should work the same for any application that allows you to drag a file onto its icon.

Comment: @Barmar, sure, but "any application that allows you to drag a file onto its icon" isn't *every application*. There's a lot of UNIX world available on OS X as lightweight ports that don't play nice with native APIs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OK, any application that follows Apple's design guidelines. Which is most.

Comment: Yup, I'll buy / agree with that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`open`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) command:

```
open -a 'Sublime Text' .
```

This uses the same `LaunchServices` mechanism as `Finder` when you click on an application, so it will only open one instance of the application.

Comment: Thanks @barmar. This is still opening the application in a new window for me.

Comment: It should be a new window but the same application process. You should only see one instance in the Dock.

Comment: @TravisHoki What happens if you drag a file or folder onto the Sublime Text icon in the Dock?

Comment: @TravisHoki If you need more elaborate control of the application, like telling it to close other windows, you'll need to use AppleScript. You can do this from the shell using `osascript`.

Comment: @Barmar When I drag a folder onto the Sublime Text Icon in the doc, it opens up a new blank window in Sublime. If I drag a file, it will open the file. The above `open` command is opening directories in new windows and only one instance, as you said. I just want to only have one window open at a time. I'll look into `osascript`. Thanks for your help.